# Make variable using non-English character

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I make variable using non English character.
for example if I use Japanese character like this :

```
あ = 10
```

I get this error :

```
Unsupported characters in input
```

or if I use Arabic character like this:

```
أ = 'Something'
```

I get another error :

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note : When I make variable using non English character in `php` it worked but in Python it does not work.
So How can I make variable using non English character in python ?

Comment: Different programming languages have different rules for variable names.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, at least not in Python 2. You can *only* use ASCII letters, digits and underscores in Python names (with digits only allowed as long as they are not the first character).

See the [Identifiers and keywords](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) section of the documentation:

> ```
> identifier ::=  (letter|"_") (letter | digit | "_")*
> letter     ::=  lowercase | uppercase
> lowercase  ::=  "a"..."z"
> uppercase  ::=  "A"..."Z"
> digit      ::=  "0"..."9"
> ```

Python 3 [has expanded what is permissible](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). Anything that is considered a Unicode letter or digit is allowed, plus underscores (and numbers not at the start).